# How to hide schema section in Swagger UI 5.0.0 for OpenAPI spec 3.1.x?

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui

We are consuming Swagger UI version 5.0.0 for displaying the API specifications. Our requirement is to show the API references in one page and the Schema view in another page.

For OpenAPI specifications 3.0.x, setting the following attribute to the configuration helps but not so for OpenAPI specifications 3.1.x.

```
defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?